# Logical calculation in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need advice/help. I am working on calculation in excel where I have data like mentioned below.

```
.    A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H         
1|   A275     A277     A273     A777     A777     TOTAL    A222     GRAND TOTAL
2|   5        7        4        3        4        7        7
```

Now, I want to count row 2 based on the header.
Here is the condition.
**If A1 <> B1 then take A1, if B1 <> C1 then take B1, if C1 <> D1 then C1, so on.**

But tricky part is...
**If D1<>E1 then D1 else (if E1<>F1 then E1 else (if F1 = "TOTAL" then F1 else(if F1<>G1 then F1)))**
In short H2 should have **30** and not **37**.

***Added comments:------------------------------------***
So, Basically **if A1<>B1 then take A1 but if A1=B1 then take B1, but then for B1, its a same rule like if B1<>C1 then take B1, but if B1=C1 then take C1 and for C1, same rule.** Stopping point will be **"TOTAL"**. **Along with these logic I need to check if any cell in row 1 is "TOTAL" then take value for same column. Now  this "TOTAL" can be in any cell in row 1.**
So from above table my calculation will be **5(A2) + 7(B2) + 4(C2) + 7(F2) + 7(G2) = 30**
**In this calculation I have not included D2 and E2 as D2=E2 so I took D2, here E2<>F2 so I should have taken E2, but as F2="TOTAL" so I took F2 and not D2 and E2.**
I hope this make sense. *(Sorry, I know its confusing.)*
I have data in more then 100 columns.
Can this be achieved using **Macro**?
**------------------------------------------------------------**

Another pain point is data and header are dynamic, so I can't have a fix format. Logic should be in a way that can handle the dynamic data and header.

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `If A1 <> B1 then take A1` - does this go to `A2`? What if `A1=B1`?

Comment: @Taosique, thanks for looking in. I have added comment, I hope this will help.

Comment: So... You want in cell `H2` sum of all cell starting from `A2` until there's a word "TOTAL" in the header above?

Comment: @Taosique, total(**30**) of **5(A2) + 7(B2) + 4(C2) + 7(F2) + 7(G2)** will be in **H2**. I have to include **G2** as well in calculation as it is last and can not be compare with following cell.

Comment: If there are three adjascent identical values in header? Take only the last one unless it's followed by "Total"?

Comment: @Taosique, yes correct but identical value can be more then 3 and good thing is if identical cells are found then it will always be followed by "TOTAL". So we just have to take value from "TOTAL" and not from any of the identical cells before "TOTAL". Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the results you want with this.

Add a helper row. In cell `A3` write this formula and drag it to the right:

```
=IF(OR(A$1=B$1,B$1="TOTAL"),0,1)
```

Calculate sum in say cell `H4` (not `H2` because if the formula refers to entire row `2` there will be circular reference):

```
=SUMIF($3:$3,1,$2:$2)
```

Comment: genius, super, awesome. How did you do that? Can please explain me. Thanks a ton man.

Comment: You're welcome! First in helper row you need to determine whether the value participates in the grand total. The condition for that is "Value in the next cell to the right is not the same as in the cell above and is not TOTAL". Then based on values in that helper row you calculate the sum.

Comment: thanks again. It really helps. Every time I come to know new thing in excel, it makes me wonder how powerful Excel is and what would happen without Excel. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Nice to see a properly asked and resolved question on SO. Excel is cool, sure.